# Java Web start - how to detect when app is closed?

Tags: java, browser, cross-browser, java-web-start, browser-detection

How do you detect when an App is open or closed?

1. User clicks on link/button.
2. Web Browser launches Java desktop app via Java Web Start.

At this point how do you have the browser detect if the App is able to launch or unable to launch, if the app has launched and closed by the user?

Comment: it must be cooperative, i.e. java application send the closing notification to the server and your web application forwards to the browser. In effect you are asking about inter-process communication, that's how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you registered the class containing `windowClosing()` method via `addWindowListener()`?

Java explicitly allows you to close process, please check below code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // you can write your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> ..how do you have the browser detect if the App is able to launch ..

Start with having the app. inform the server that it has started (or is about to exit).  Then set up some mechanism for the browser to poll the server.